# Convertir un objeto en array de objetos

Tags: javascript, json, array

Tengo datos que me regresa una api de esta manera

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "id_analisis_modena": 2221,
        "fecha": "2020-04-07",
        "monedas_cien": 0,
        "monedas_veinte": 0,
        "monedas_diez": 2,
        "monedas_cinco": 17,
        "monedas_dos": 11,
        "monedas_uno": 2,
        "monedas_cincuenta_centavos": 1,
        "monedas_veinte_centavos": 2,
        "monedas_diez_centavos": 0,
        "monedas_cinco_centavos": 0,
        "billetes_mil": 0,
        "billetes_quinientos": 6,
        "billetes_doscientos": 5,
        "billetes_cien": 25,
        "billetes_cincuenta": 19,
        "billetes_veinte": 19,
        "diferencia": 0,
        "monedas_un_centavos": 0
    }
}
```

lo convierto con esto

```
const moneyDatas = Object.entries(moneyData).map(i => i[1]);
```

y me regresa esto:

```
money: Array(2)
0: "success"
1: {id_analisis_modena: 2022, fecha: "2020-04-06", monedas_cien: 0, monedas_veinte: 0, monedas_diez: 15, …}
```

habra manera de eliminar ese "success" y solo quedarme con el resto del array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es que estoy entendiendo bien, se supone que esta bien simple, porque si tiene ese objeto y quieres la propiedad data, solamente la seleccionas :

```
//así te quedas solo con los datos 
//asumiedo que lo que estás trayendo del fetch es un json
const aux = dataFetched.data 
const array = Object.entries(aux);
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que solo quieres acceder a la propiedad `data`. Tienes que ver la estructura de objeto y acceder las propiedades que quieras.

Puedes hacerlo así.

```js
const response = {
    "message": "success",
    "data": {
        "id_analisis_modena": 2221,
        "fecha": "2020-04-07",
        "monedas_cien": 0,
        "monedas_veinte": 0,
        "monedas_diez": 2,
        "monedas_cinco": 17,
        "monedas_dos": 11,
        "monedas_uno": 2,
        "monedas_cincuenta_centavos": 1,
        "monedas_veinte_centavos": 2,
        "monedas_diez_centavos": 0,
        "monedas_cinco_centavos": 0,
        "billetes_mil": 0,
        "billetes_quinientos": 6,
        "billetes_doscientos": 5,
        "billetes_cien": 25,
        "billetes_cincuenta": 19,
        "billetes_veinte": 19,
        "diferencia": 0,
        "monedas_un_centavos": 0
    }
}

const dataArray = [response.data]

console.log(dataArray)
```

Comment: Gracias, funciono al 100!!! aun soy nuevo en esto de los arrays jajaja, gracias!!!